# Automapper map from nested class to single (flatten)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper

This is my source:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string State {get; set; }
}
```

This is my destination:

```
public class UserVM
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

How do I do the mapping? The normal create map doesn't work when they say flattening is automatic.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you change your destination class property names to `AddressStreet` and `AddressState`, AutoMapper will, by convention, match them to `Address.Street` and `Address.State` on the source.

```
public class UserVM
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string AddressStreet { get; set; } // User.Address.Street
    public string AddressState { get; set; }  // User.Address.State
}
```

Alternatively, you leave your destination property names as is and use custom member mappings:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserVM>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Street, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Address.Street))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.State, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Address.State));
```

See the AutoMapper documentation for [Projection](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Projection) and [Flattening](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Flattening) for more information.

Comment: How deep down does this go? What if I have that User with children who also have addresses?

Comment: @Lolcoder, I'm not sure; I don't see any limits mentioned in the documentation.  Might be worth a new question for someone more familiar with AutoMapper than I am.

Comment: Is there an easy way to do the reverse of this with the same convention?

Comment: Alternatively can have 2 `CreateMap`, one for `Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserVM>()` and one for `Mapper.CreateMap<Address, UserVM>()`. The latter will need custom member mappings similar to original @JeffOgata answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was stumped by this issue and this solved it for me. I assume in your code, AutoMapper is being injected by your DI container

```
public class MappingProfile: Profile
{

    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<User, UserVM>()
           .IncludeMembers(u => u.Address);
        CreateMap<Address, UserVM>();
    }
}
```