# Join two object with Automapper

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I have two objects like this :

Target:
ID,
Name,
Size

Service:
TargetId,
text

I am trying to map both of them to a destination object like this:

Link:
ID,
Name,
Size,
Text . ..where (service.targetId==Target.ID)

Can I add a linq query to the Map profile to do that?

Comment: Not trying to be rude, but there's dozens of questions like this and it's called "flatten" "flattening".  Try this google: `site:stackoverflow.com automapper flatten` look at answers, and make some attempts using some of those approaches.  Hopefully you'll find a solution there.  If you get close but have trouble with certain approaches, then you can post a more specific question with what you had tried. Good luck.

Comment: This is a one to one but not a nested relationship

Comment: This is what you want then.  Address is same as your Target since it's the parent in the relationship. You'll need to have a navigation property from Target to Service so you can do `MapFrom( src => src.Service.text`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8058783/84206